# How do I compile a c++ file on mac?

Tags: c++, macos

The code I have tried porting from windows to compile c++ on a mac does not work.

```
g++ -W -Wall -pedantic filename.cpp
```

Comment: In what way does it not work? Does it not compile? Does it give you unexpected results? We need more information.

Comment: I already have Xcode, it just was not giving me the executable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following:

g++ -o filename filename.cpp

Comment: thanks, that does the trick

Answer (score -1):

You could also use XCode.
But ofc, not all the cpp files from Windows could be directly ported on mac: it depends on their content.
You should consider also something like this:
http://mac.sillydog.org/dev/visual_studio.php
Best